# How can I auto-destroy QMediaPlayer?

Tags: qt

I use this snippet of code from Qt documentation to play audio files in my application (notification etc):

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/huggle/sounds/" + file));
player->setVolume(100);
player->play();
```

This however looks to me like it's gonna leak, as there is no destructor for media player.

Is there a way to delete it after it finishes playing in a non-blocking way? Probably hooking some events would work, but it's not clear which.

Comment: Why create it on the heap in the first place?

Comment: @MrEricSir because it's within a function, if I define it on stack, it will be immediately destroyed before it starts playing sound. play() is async function and returns immediately, so the object would be destroyed upon exit of function that created it.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense -- instantiate it within the class it lives in, or even global scope if you must. This seems like a larger issue with misunderstanding object lifecycles in C++ than anything specific to QMediaPlayer.

Comment: @MrEricSir I am sure how or why you judge my understanding of object lifecycle with no knowledge about the context here, but to clarify, this is a static function: https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx/blob/audio/huggle/resources.cpp#L84 placing it on stack simply makes no sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the signal `QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)` with the status being `QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia` I guess!?

Or just save the pointer to `QMediaPlayer` in your class for later use.

```
connect(player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)), SLOT(player_mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));


// slot
void YourClass::player_mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
    if (status == QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia)
        sender()->deleteLater(); // will schedule the deletion of your QMediaPlayer (sender of this signal)
}
```

Comment: I don't really have any later use... I could probably as well make a timer that just checks after some period and removes objects that are refered by old pointers, but that is kinda ugly solution :/

Comment: Why use a timer, just schedule it for auto deletion in the `QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged` signal!? I change my answer to provide a code sample.

Comment: what if this signal isn't emitted due to playback issues?